# Python PPTX read slide number (page number)

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm doing a custom table of content for slides that is generated by Python-PPTX.
For the slides, footer and slide numbers already set up, and I can already view it in resulting PPTX. I believe slide numbers already exist, just needed to be read.

My question is, whether the slide number information is accessible from slide object, or perhaps somewhere else? Overall script looks like this:

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation()
for x in 'abc':
    s = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[6])

    if x=='b':
        s.placeholders[0].text = <str: page number of current slide 's'>
```

Comment: I am content with using index position of the slide, within parent container i.e. prs.slides for now to address my problem, though this is not the technical solution to the question

Comment: can you please share the exact code you are using to reference the slide numbers? I am trying to reference existing slides to print dataframe on the same but i am getting stuck at referencing the specific slide number.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59496023/6389099

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no slide number attribute of a slide as far as I know, all a slide number is is the position of the slide in the presentation. The slide number that appears in a footer is a *sld-num* field element, that displays this position when you are in the PowerPoint application, but this number is calculated the same way.

It could be there is some special behavior when you create a custom slide show, like skipping slide numbers that are "hidden", but I haven't experimented with that.

For general purposes, the easiest way to get it is like this:

```
slides = prs.slides
for slide in slides:
    print('slide number %d' % slides.index(slide)+1)
```

I'm not sure if that's what you were talking about in your comment, but using the `index()` method on `Slides` is perhaps more flexible than something like:

```
for idx, slide in enumerate(slides):
    print('slide number %d' % idx+1)
```

or

```
def slide_number(slides, slide):
    for idx, s is enumerate(slides):
         if s == slide:
             return idx+1
```

You do need to have references to both `slides` and the `slide` to make it work.

Comment: yes, I'm using something like prs.slides.index(s) + 1 , to get the 'slide number' for s. thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

You can access the slide number using index() method.

```
slide_id = prs.slides.index(slide)
```

To access slide with slide id you can use get() method.

```
slide = prs.slides.get(slide_id)
```

Please refer the below link for more information:

https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/slides.html

Answer (score -1):

You can count each slides number and total number.

First, Get each slide number.

```
for slide in prs.slides:
    slide_cnt = slide_cnt + 1
    print(slide_cnt)
```

Second, Get the total number of slides.

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation("path/example.pptx")
print(len(prs.slides))
```

Comment: OP's question is about 'reading' the slide number from the footer / slide, not about a counter for index of each slide.